# Textarea и событие blur jquery

Tags: jquery, события, javascript, textarea

Здравствуйте. Скажите пожалуйста почему не работает следующий код:

> **$("textarea").blur(console.log($(this).val()));**

?

Например,

> **$("input[type='text']").blur(console.log($(this).val()));**

работает отлично. С разметкой все ок перепроверял.

Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни то, ни другое не должны работать.
Правильно так:

```
$("textarea").blur(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы.

Comment: @z_coder, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).